# PHP Regex: Pattern to match "url()"

Tags: php, regex

This Regex:

```
$pattern = '/url\(([^)]+)\)/';
```

matches everything between `url( ... )` in CSS files. The problem: If there are quotes, like this: `url('...')`, they occur in the returned phrase as well.

How to return a phrase without quotes, if there are any?

Comment: Applies to single and double quotes....

Comment: The same story over and over again. Someone asks "how to parse <some structured language> with regexes". Someone comments "regexes are not the tool, use a parser". Someone answers with a half-baked regex that kinda works for a particular case. Many thanks, answer accepted, end of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url\(['"]?([^)]+?)['"]?\)
```

This should do it for you.Make `' or "` optional.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/27

Comment: Thank you. I am testing right now. It takes a while because it fetches files to generate an appcache manifest in a big project :)

Comment: i don't know how he wants an invalid match.

Comment: It's OK, it is our own project so we take care about such things. The answer is absolutely perfect for my needs. Will accept it as soon as SO allows me to :)

Comment: @BarthZalewski you can refer to demo as well.Now it handles all the cases.

Comment: @AvinashRaj now it takes care of your concern too :)

Comment: @vks no .  It won't match this `url(foo")` string. It's a wrong format. As op said there isn't a string like this. So no probs..

Comment: @AvinashRaj it will grab `foo` .that what you want right?

Comment: I think exactly like vks. If it matches misspelled URI-s, it's even better. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: @BarthZalewski yes that should be the behavious acc. to me. :)

Comment: @BarthZalewski If that's the case then you could use your regex and just `trim()` double and single quotes all the time. Just saying...

Comment: How can I `trim()` quotes?

Comment: Oh, I forgot something. You might need to use `str_replace()` after all. [demo](https://eval.in/210846). Here's a [regex](http://regex101.com/r/wI1fB3/1) that works and detects even broken quotes.